# how to use bulma's flexbox to make footer stick to bottom of page?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, bulma

I've just started learning about reactjs and bulma.css. I'm trying to make a `<footer>` to stick to the bottom of the page using bulma's flexbox since I want to avoid writing my own css rules.

I already installed bulma using npm and imported bulma.css in the index.js like this

```
import "bulma/css/bulma.css";
```

but my code below still makes the `<footer>` to stick under the header..

```
<div className='container'>
  <header className='has-text-centered'>
    <h1>My Store</h1>
  </header>

  <div>
    <h2>Dashboard Title</h2>
  </div>

  <footer className="has-text-centered is-flex-align-items-flex-end">
    <small>
      <span>Copyright @2022</span>
      <br />
    </small>
    <a href="/">About</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straightforward-bulma way would look something like:

1. Make sure the body and html are the full page height
   Since this is every project-dependent, I've used the classic `body { height: 100vh; }` for now
2. The same for the `container`, it needs to be enlarged. Using the `is-fullheight` from the `hero` elements can be used (note: Consider using a hero instead of the container)
3. Give the footer a `mt-auto` which is short for `margin-top: auto`. This will force the footer to stick to the bottom of the page

```css
html, body { height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">

<div class='container hero is-fullheight'>
  <header class='has-text-centered'>
    <h1>My Store</h1>
  </header>

  <div>
    <h2>Dashboard Title</h2>
  </div>

  <footer class="has-text-centered is-flex-align-items-flex-end mt-auto">
    <small>
      <span>Copyright @2022</span>
      <br />
    </small>
    <a href="/">About</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! the `is-fullheight` and `mt-auto` classes did the job.